# Customize Highcharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm customizing Highcharts tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    pointFormat: 'round {point.x-9} to {point.x} avg: {point.y}'
}
```

but `{point.x-10}` can't be evaluated, instead of getting `round 0 to 9 avg: 0.1`, I have `round to 9 avg: 0.1`.

How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I think you should use the formatter option

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts do not allow you to execute JS code in curly brackets. In API we can read:

> **pointFormat: String:** The HTML of the point's line in the tooltip. Variables are enclosed by curly brackets. Available variables are point.x, point.y, series. name and series.color and other properties on the same form.

You should use formatter property:

```
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
  formatter: function() {
    return 'round ' + (this.x - 9) + ' to ' + this.x + ' avg: ' + this.y
  }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8xn5sv3t/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat